# Not able to understand javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute the following code

```
var n = 100;
var sum =0;
while(n>0)
{
sum = sum + n%10;
n = n/10;
}
console.log(sum);
```

The result should be 1 but javascript is returning

> 1.1111111111111112

Also, when I ran individual statements it is giving perfectly fine result,
what could be the possible reason?

Comment: first iteration n = 100, second n = 10, 3rd n = 1, 4th n= 0.1, 5th n=0.01, until n is small enough to be equal to 0, at 1e-324 on my machine

Comment: *The result should be 1*: Why?

Comment: Why would you think that it should be 1? When `n` goes into decimal numbers `0.1%10 == 0.1`, `0.01%10 == 0.01` you get `n` back so as you add them to the previous sum you get `1.1111.....` Also you are lucky that at certain precision the value just becomes 0 as otherwise you would have an infinite loop

Comment: `n%10` for numbers less than `10` is `n`. The numbers don't have to be integers for it to work (maybe they should? who knows)

Comment: `n/10` will return a floating value. Use `n=parseInt(n/10)`

Answer (score 7):

The result it is giving is correct -

Lets go into while loop

For first iteration n=100 so n%10 = 0 and sum = 0, after first loop sum = 0 and n = 10

In second iteration n%10 = 0 and sum = 0,
after second iteration sum = 0 and n = 1

For third iteration n%10 = 1 and sum =0,
after third iteration sum = 1 and n = 0.1

For fourth iteration n%10 = 0.1 and sum = 1,
after fourth iteration sum = 1.1 and n = 0.01

and so on so forth

finally the answer would be 1.1111111111....... tending to infinity so it becomes 1.1111111111111112

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

If you want final answer as 1, intialise n as 0.9(n = 0.9)

Comment: Finally! someone has come up to present the fact that OP's expectation is incorrect, instead of just rounding a number down to a completely invalid value. Way to go!

Comment: while this anwer declares what happen, the op does not get what is requested, a result with one.

Comment: @NinaScholz Edited, getting final answer as 1 is just playing with numbers here and there

Answer (score 2):

No, the result won't be 1. Notice that your loop is dividing `n` by 10 every iteration, and that the continuing condition is `n > 0`, which will take many iterations till it happens:

- n=100, n%10=0
- n=10, n%10=0
- n=1, n%10=1
- n=0.1, n%10=0.1
- n=0.01, n%10=0.01
- ...

So, the result is correct: 1.1111111... The 2 at the end is no more than a rounding decimal error (minimal).